# How do I make sense of all the widget sizes and size policies while designing a dialog in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, widget, size, qt-designer

I often have problems getting the sizes of the widgets right while designing parts of a GUI in Creator. Consider the following example, a dialog:

http://grafit.mchtr.pw.edu.pl/~szczedar/designer.png

I am trying to make the "Images" groupbox have fixed width, I want the "Size" groupbox which shares a vertical layout with "Images" to adjust to "Images"' size horizontally, and the "Image view" to grab every inch of space available, but I've no idea how to do this. When I set the maximum width of Images to 300, and set the horizontal policy to "Fixed", it reduces its size and sticks to it, but the "Size" box is unchanged. I tried changing the spacer's settings and policies, but it doesn't do what I want. The "Image view" box has a policy of "Preferred" in both directions and works mostly OK.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the layout of the main widget is a `QGridLayout`, go in the properties of the layout, and change:

- the `layoutColumnStretch` property to "0, 1", to prevent the first column which contains the "Images" groupbox to never grow from its minimum width, and to make the second column take all the remaining space.
- the `layoutColumnMinimumWidth` property to "300, 0" (or "300, something else") to set the minimum size of that same column.

You might also have to reset all the other settings you tried to change (policies, and min/max sizes of the individual group boxes) to their default values.